# Can Cocoa embed an SDL window?

Tags: cocoa, sdl

I am trying some SDL games porting to mac OS X.

I want to use the Cocoa window as the main window to manage a few games, so I want to embed the SDL window into the Cocoa window as a child window.

Is that possible? If so, can you show me some examples?

Answer (score 1):

SDL uses a Cocoa window internally, so it should be possible to embed it in some larger Cocoa hierarchy. A while back, I added additional (Cocoa) windows to an SDL-based game engine, so I'm pretty sure this can work. Take a look at the Cocoa port of SDL and you should see where it sets up the window hierarchy.

Comment: @zhouquanxia thanks. If you find my answer helpful, it's polite to accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.